# Use distinct() on a variable in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I'm trying several queries in mongodb. Each document of my colelction is like this :

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"name" : 1,
"isReferenceProteome" : 1,
"isRepresentativeProteome" : 1,
"component" : 1,
"reference" : 1,
"upid" : 1,
"modified" : 1,
"taxonomy" : 1,
"superregnum" : 1,
"description" : 1,
"dbReference" : 1
}
```

the "reference" field has nested fields, one is "authorList", an array containing 'name' fields.

```
"reference" {
    "authorList" [
        {"name": "author1"},
        {"name": "author2"},
        {"name": "author3"} ...etc...
    ]
}
```

I have stored in a variable the result of the following query :

var testing = db.mycollection.find({'reference.authorList.30': {$exists: true}})

which stores all documents where the authorList is at least 30 names long.

Then I wanted to use distinct() on this variable, in order to have the distinct names of all authors :

```
testing.distinct("reference.authorList.name")
```

I tried this way because my first query returned an empty array :

```
db.mycollection.distinct( "reference.authorList.name", {"reference.authorList.name.30": {$exists: true}} )
```

I'm also trying whit `$where` command, but I got syntaxError for now.

What I am missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to get distinct names in 30 names ? or is it just a check to see if it contains 30 names and get distinct names for all names ? Btw `db.mycollection.distinct( "reference.authorList.name", {"reference.authorList.30": {$exists: true}} )`. This will output **all** distinct names when there is at least 30 names.

Comment: Silly me, i was using "reference.authorList.name.30" instead of "reference.authorList.30" ... Yes, I wanted to have distinct names only for authorLists > 30 names. I got it now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
db.head_human_prot.distinct( "reference.authorList.name", {"reference.authorList.30": {$exists: true}} )
```

instead of

```
db.head_human_prot.distinct( "reference.authorList.name", {"reference.authorList.name.30": {$exists: true}} )
```

Silly me...